# bootstrapping large data similar to Python's matplotlib-seaborn lineplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, statistics-bootstrap

I have a large dataset that takes ages to [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) and plot with [seaborn's lineplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html). I want to try plotting it with Gnuplot. As an **reprex** one can export the `fmri` dataset of seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
fmr.to_csv('out.csv')
```

```
         

                              image courtesy of pydata.org.
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me know if/how this could be done in Gnuplot.

Comment: I am not aware that gnuplot has a built-in bootstrapping method. gnuplot wants to be a plotting tool, not a data analysis tool, although it has some built-in basic statistics. But which of the many different bootstrapping methods are you looking for? If you have a link about the specific method where it is described in detail what needs to be done, I could have a look at it.

Comment: Dear @theozh this post is from research I was doing back in 2019 and I do not recall the details nor do I no longer have access to the datasets/codes I was working on. I just edited the post because the link to the former image was broken. Otherwise, I do really appreciate your kind offer. 

Answer (score 2):

To create this plot I used a file called `data.dat` containing 4 columns.

```
#  x      y    ylow   yhigh
 0.000  0.004  0.004  0.005
 1.000  0.029  0.024  0.022
 2.000  0.137  0.089  0.063
 3.000  0.414  0.176  0.116
 4.000  0.806  0.185  0.148
 5.000  1.011  0.154  0.154
 6.000  0.821  0.192  0.153
 7.000  0.445  0.188  0.129
 8.000  0.189  0.109  0.085
 9.000  0.110  0.056  0.054
10.000  0.118  0.049  0.051
11.000  0.152  0.061  0.061
12.000  0.189  0.076  0.075
13.000  0.221  0.089  0.088
14.000  0.242  0.097  0.097
15.000  0.250  0.100  0.100
16.000  0.242  0.097  0.097
17.000  0.221  0.089  0.088
18.000  0.189  0.076  0.075
19.000  0.152  0.061  0.060
20.000  0.114  0.045  0.046
```

The `gnuplot` script:

```
reset
# Setting encoding
set encoding utf8
# Setting terminal
set terminal wxt font "Ubuntu,10"
# Turn-off the key/legend
unset key
# Setting the grid 
set grid ls -1 lw 1 lc "white" back
# Setting the tick marks
set tics scale 0.001
# Axes' ranges
set xrange [-1:21]
set yrange [-0.1:1.25]
# Axes' labels
set xlabel "timepoint"
set ylabel "signal"
# Formats to ticks
set format x "%.1f"
set format y "%.2f"
# Force the entire area enclosed by the axes to have background color gray
set object rectangle from graph 0,0 to graph 1,1 fc rgb "gray" fs transp solid 0.5 noborder behind
# Styles to line and filledcurves
set style line 1 lc rgb "#0060ad" lt 1 lw 1.5 # -> blue
set style fill transparent solid 0.5
# The graph itself
plot \
    "data.dat" u 1:($2-$3):($2+$4) w filledcurves ls 1,\
    "data.dat" u 1:2 w lines ls 1
```

The result:

[image: graph]

Comment: but here you did not bootstrap the date. You considered a `yhigh` and `ylow`! please consider that bootstrapping is more important than how the graph looks like.

Comment: I'm really sorry! I have no experience with bootstrapping. I thought that the difficulty was create the chart. I hope that someone could give a more helpful answer. Good luck!